# Specifying the primitive type of a property in a Cypher CREATE clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Contrary to what's [possible](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/graphdb-neo4j-properties.html) with the Java API, there doesn't seem to be a way to specify whether a numeric property is a `byte`, `short`, `int` or `long`:

```
CREATE (n:Test {value: 1}) RETURN n
```

always seems to create a `long` property. I've tried `toInt()`, but it is obviously understood in the mathematical sense of "integer" more than in the computer data type sense.

Is there some way I'm overlooking to actually force the type?

We have defined a model and want to insert test data using Cypher statements, but the code using the data then fails with a `ClassCastException` since the types don't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run your cypher queries with the embedded API then
you can provide parameters in a hashmap with the correctly typed values.

For remote users it doesn't really matter as it goes through JSON serialization back and forth which looses the type information anyway. So it is just "numeric".

Why do you care about the numeric type?

you can also just use `((Number)n.getProperty("value")).xxxValue()` (xxx = int,long,byte)

Comment: I cared about the types because Neo4j supports different types itself, so it would have been useful to actually use the most appropriate one to avoid wasting (disk) space, for example. Also it seems a bit overkill to use a `long` in the code to represent a rounded percentage, so we'd been using `int` for that (yes, I know it fits in a `byte`). What you say about JSON serialization is enlightening, actually, because it means we'll actually end up with `long` storage for everything as the data is inserted using Spring Data Neo4j in remote mode. I guess we'll directly go with `long`s everywhere.

Comment: As a side note, using `Number.xxxValue()` is a bit heavier and less readable than just `(int) n.getProperty("value")`.